# Syntax Error with convert_obj_three.py

Tags: python, 3d, three.js, webgl

Whenever I try to convert my obj file I get a syntax error on line 781.

```
C:\Users\Paul>cd "C:\Users\Paul\Documents\GitHub\three.js\utils\converters\obj"

C:\Users\Paul\Documents\GitHub\three.js\utils\converters\obj>python convert_obj_
three.py -i dragon.obj -o dragon.js -x 1000
File "convert_obj_three.py", line 781
print "WARNING: skipping morph [%s] with different number of vertices [%d] t
han the original model [%d]" % (name, n_morph_vertices, n_vertices)

                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am not sure what is going on.  I checked what I was doing against others who have had success and I don't seem to be doing anything wrong.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you by chance running the file with Python 3.x? That is valid Python 2.x syntax, but it is **not** valid Python 3.x syntax.

Comment: I am using 3.3 so that is probably the issue.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: You're most welcome. You can have more than one version installed so the main thing is ensuring your script gets run by the appropriate one. The most-recent 2.x is 2.7.3 available here: http://www.python.org/getit/

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned in your comment that you're using Python 3.3, you can fix this by changing your print statement to use 3.x's string `format` operator (and `print()` as a function):

```
print(
    "WARNING: skipping morph {} with different number of vertices {} "
    "than the original model {}".format(name, n_morph_vertices, n_vertices)
)
```

Or you can just run the same script using a python 2.x interpreter without any changes.